# How do you remove the aerator from a Hans Grohe kitchen faucet/sprayer?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

How do you disassemble this sprayer head to replace (or at least clean) the aerator?  It says "Hans Grohe" on the front base of the faucet, but I can't find a model number.  It was a "Costco special" maybe 5 years ago.

Front:

[image: Hansgrohe sprayer front]

[image: hansgrohe sink sprayer front]

Rear:

[image: hansgrohe sink sprayer rear 1]

[image: hansgrohe sink sprayer rear 2]

Comment: Put in an inch of vinegar.  Leave sit for a few minutes and rinse out.

Comment: Did you search the internet for "Hans Grohe aerator wrench"?

Comment: @FreeMan until now, I didn't even know that an aerator wrench was a thing...but now I'm on the right track!

Answer (score 7):

Use the hans grohe aerator wrench.

[image: aerator wrench]

https://www.grohe.ca/bathroom-faucet-fittings-and-spare-parts/disassembling-key/grohe-chrome-48021000

Amazon has generic recessed aerator wrenches available as well.